# No Call Operator

Tags: c++

```
 struct Boy {
    map<string,int> girlLookUp;
    string Name;
 };

 struct Girl {
    map<string,int> boyLookUp;
    string Name;
 };

 int findSumBoyGirl(Boy a, Girl b)
 {
    Boy *p = &a;
    Girl *s = &b;

    int sum = p->girlLookUp(s->Name) + s->boyLookUp(p->Name); "----Error----"

    return sum;
 }
```

I am attempting to retrieve an associated gender value by looking up the name of the opposite gender for each respective person. When I do this I get an error "Map does not provide a call operator." I do not understand the context of this warning. Is it not possible to do what I am attempting?

Comment: Not related to the error, but why the pointers? Why not `return a.girlLookUp[s->Name] + b.boyLookUp[p->Name];`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use `map::operator[]`. It means you should have

```
p->girlLookUp[s->Name] + s->boyLookUp[p->Name];
```

Comment: Also see the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) for more details (and other functions std::map supports)

Answer (score 2):

It thinks you're trying to use `operator()()`, which is not overloaded for `std::map`. Either use `operator[]` or if you have C++11, `at`. i.e.,

```
Girl girl;
girl.boyLookUp["hi"];
girl.boyLookUp.at("hi");
```